# can't add new objects on canvas (fabric.js)

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working on a project using fabric.js and facing this problem.

i have a function fun() and its called on event onclick, so basically i am expecting a circle everytime i click on my screen but as result all i get is a blank screen. alerting the objetcs sure gives me the number of objects with the type circle and is incremented everytime i click on the screen but i cant see the circles on the screen, its like the cirlces are there but not visible.

here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Sunny\Documents\6th Sem Ka Maal\Graph\project\GUI\fabric.js-1.5.0\dist\fabric.js"></script>
<script>

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('p');
function fun(event){

var x = event.clientX;
var y = event.clientY;
alert(x);
alert(y);
alert(canvas);
var circle= new fabric.Circle({
radius: 50, fill: 'green', left: x, top: y
});
alert(circle);
canvas.add(circle);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="p" height="993" width="1920" onclick="fun(event)"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

why am i not able to see the circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wiring up the event in Javascript instead, using Fabric's `on()` listener.

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', fun);
```

Read more about fabric events here:

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events

Last year I was messing around with Fabric for an OU project for point-to-point drawing, you can have a look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/zm2cX/6/) might give you some ideas.

Comment: And the explanation to why: `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('p');` At this point in time, the element "p" does not yet exist, so fabric creates a wrapper for a non existing canvas. Then you create a real canvas and bind onclick to a function that makes calls to your fabric-wrapper with a non-existing canvas.

Comment: garryp's answer is correct. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wL3kpawg/) with what he said ... And please use `console.log()` for debugging and not alert. Ex: `console.log(canvas)`, `console.log(x)`, etc. You will see the response in browser's Console.